# Add multiple rows based on date using proc sql on Netezza server

Tags: sql, netezza, proc

I'm working with stored procedures in netezza. I want to create 12 dates by adding months to the date of birth of a person. 
I want to add_months(dob,1) 12 times for every person in the list.Any ideas of how to achieve it , really appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the procedural approach but using sql you can get the output as desired .

**Create a indicator table :**

```
create table test (indicator int);
insert into test values (0);
insert into test values (1);
insert into test values (2);
insert into test values (3);
insert into test values (4);
insert into test values (5);
insert into test values (6);
insert into test values (7);
insert into test values (8);
insert into test values (9);
insert into test values (10);
insert into test values (11);
```

**Original table containing values :**

```
create table test1 (col1 char(5),col2 date);

insert into test1 values ('A','01-Jan-2000');
insert into test1 values ('A2','03-Mar-1998');
```

**Now the final query to get the output:**

```
SELECT col1
    ,to_char(add_months(col2, indicator), 'DD-MM-YYYY') as_date
FROM test1
    ,test
ORDER BY col1
    ,as_date;
```

**Output:**

```
A   1/1/2000
A   1/2/2000
A   1/3/2000
A   1/4/2000
A   1/5/2000
A   1/6/2000
A   1/7/2000
A   1/8/2000
A   1/9/2000
A   1/10/2000
A   1/11/2000
A   1/12/2000
A2  3/1/1999
A2  3/2/1999
A2  3/3/1998
A2  3/4/1998
A2  3/5/1998
A2  3/6/1998
A2  3/7/1998
A2  3/8/1998
A2  3/9/1998
A2  3/10/1998
A2  3/11/1998
A2  3/12/1998
```